# samesite is not working for ngcookies in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, cookies, samesite

I am using ngCookies for my Angular JS project.  I am trying to set samesite option as strict(as mentioned below), but it's not working.  Could anyone please help me how can I set samesite for Angular JS cookies?

I tried as per this Angular JS documentation, I see all other options are getting set but the samesite is not getting set as 'strict' in chrome.
[Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/provider/$cookiesProvider#defaults)

```
MyCookiesService.put('user-details', JSON.stringify(session), {
                        expires: expire.toUTCString(),
                        path: '/',
                        secure: true,
                        samesite: 'strict'
                    });
```

Comment: I suspect the issue would be with Angular JS version(1.6.10) which I am using.  samesite option is supported from the version 1.7.1.

Comment: Are you aware of any way to setting  samesite in the older versions of Angular (such Angular Js 1.4.9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved via comment from [Nirmala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56340117/samesite-is-not-working-for-ngcookies-in-angular-js#comment99289848_56340117).

My issue required `samesite: 'none'`. Confirmed code works correctly when upgraded to Angular 1.7.1+

```
MyCookiesService.put('user-details', JSON.stringify(session), {
                        expires: expire.toUTCString(),
                        path: '/',
                        secure: true,
                        samesite: 'strict'
                    });
```